# Prevent line/paragraph breaks in contentEditable

Tags: javascript, firefox, contenteditable

When using contentEditable in Firefox, is there a way to prevent the user from inserting paragraph or line breaks by pressing enter or shift+enter?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can attach an event handler to the keydown or keypress event for the contentEditable field and cancel the event if the keycode identifies itself as enter (or shift+enter).

This will disable enter/shift+enter completely when focus is in the contentEditable field.

If using jQuery, something like:

```
$("#idContentEditable").keypress(function(e){ return e.which != 13; });
```

...which will return false and cancel the keypress event on enter.

Comment: Note that this won’t work when copy-pasting text with line breaks into the contentEditable area.

Comment: Does not cover the cases for pasting (from clipboard) or dropping content.

Comment: it will be useful to handle multiple `contenteditable` elements on page, but not just one

Comment: @SystemsRebooter Just do it on different elements or use a loop

Answer (score 54):

This is possible with Vanilla JS, with the same effort:

```
document.getElementById('idContentEditable').addEventListener('keypress', (evt) => {
    if (evt.which === 13) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You should not use jQuery for the most simple things. Also, you may want to use "key" instead of "which": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

**Update, since `keypress` is deprecated:**

```
document.getElementById('idContentEditable').addEventListener('keydown', (evt) => {
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I agree, and FWIW I wasn’t using JQuery in the project that prompted this question. It does annoy me a bit that JavaScript answers on SO usually assume everyone uses JQuery, but OTOH beginners are overwhelmingly likely to be using JQuery and everyone else is capable of translating the answers to use their preferred libraries or lack thereof :).

Comment: i do see it as a big problem that beginners always try to use jquery for everything. they don´t even really learn vanilla js anymore.

Comment: Now `keyCode` is deprecated too so use `evt.key === "Enter"`. Can't speak to backwards compatibility here. [Docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values)

Comment: And in the jquery flavor: 
$(".<class_name>").keypress(function(e)
          {
            if (e.which === 13) e.preventDefault();
          });

Comment: There is a typo: evt.preventDefault should be event.preventDefault! Besides, the lambda syntax does not work in every browser. This code worked for me:
name.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( event ) {
      if ( event.keyCode === 13 ) {
       event.preventDefault();
      }
     } );

Comment: do you mean the arrow function? because it works in every important browser: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions - IE11 has no real relevance anymore. you are right about the typo though, thanx for pointing it out!

Answer (score 23):

Add the following CSS rule to *hide* line breaks. This is only a style setting, you should add some event handlers to *prevent* inserting line breaks:

```
.your_editable br {
    display: none
}
```

Comment: Chrome inserts some `<DIV>`s too, so might add `.your_editable * { display: inline }` before that.

Comment: Annoying, indeed

Comment: What a unique approach. I had an unrelated issue where the custom-styled text used to move up due to the chrome-inserted line break's deletion. Interestingly the problem resolved itself by refreshing the stylesheet from the dev tools. I lost hope until I found your solution. It works now.

Answer (score 12):

Other than adding line breaks, the browser adds additional tags and styles (when you paste text, the browser also appends your pasted text style).

The code below covers it all.

- When you press enter, no line breaks will be added.
- When you paste text, all elements added by the browser are stripped from the text.

  ```
  $('[contenteditable]').on('paste', function(e) {
      //strips elements added to the editable tag when pasting
      var $self = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {$self.html($self.text());}, 0);
  }).on('keypress', function(e) {
       //ignores enter key
       return e.which != 13;
  });
  ```

[Click here for a live example](https://jsfiddle.net/b8bb8rwv/3/)

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 7):

another option is to allow breaks to be entered but remove them on blur. this has the advantage of dealing with pasted content. your users will either love it or hate it (depending on your users).

```
function handle_blur(evt){
  var elt=evt.target; elt.innerText=elt.innerText.replace(/\n/g,' ');
}
```

then, in html:

```
<span onblur="handle_blur(event)" contenteditable>editable text</span>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using JQuery framework, you can set it with the *on* method which will let you have the desired behavior on all elements even if this one is added lately.

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.YourClass', function(e){
    return e.which != 13; 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Add:

```
display: flex;
```

On the contenteditable html element

Comment: Please add a proper explanation of how your solution addresses the question.

Comment: Simple yet perfect!

Comment: nice one and perfect !

Comment: Does not work when using shift+enter

Comment: This works in the following way: When you add a line break in a content editable element, the browser automatically wraps your lines inside a `div` element. When the line breaks, it adds a `div` element automatically to start the current new line.

By using `display: flex`, you make the DIVs appear horizontally in the same line, unlike `display: block` which is applied by default. This does not prevent the addition of new lines. It just makes them appear directly next to each other. You could confirm this behavior by using the DevTools or pressing `shift`+`enter`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#idContentEditable").keypress(function(e){ return e.which != 13; });
```

Solution proposed by Kamens doesn't work in Opera, you should attach event to document instead.

```
/**
 * Pass false to enable
 */
var disableEnterKey = function(){
    var disabled = false;

    // Keypress event doesn't get fired when assigned to element in Opera
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if (disabled) return e.which != 13;
    });                 

    return function(flag){
        disabled = (flag !== undefined) ? flag : true;
    }
}();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to target all the contentEditable fields use

```
$('[contenteditable]').keypress(function(e){ return e.which != 13; });
```

Answer (score 3):

I came here searching for the same answer, and was surprised to find it's a rather simple solution, using the tried and true [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  if (e.which === 13) e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="input">
  You can edit me, just click on me and start typing.
  However, you can't add any line breaks by pressing enter.
</div>
```

Comment: that´s exactly my answer, 3 years before yours ;)

Comment: Ah, so it is, not sure why I answered this question then, perhaps it didn’t have an accepted answer, and I didn’t see your reply; however, there is one key difference, I assigned the element to a const to make the code more readable #mindblowing

Answer (score 2):

Use the `beforeinput` event and when you hear the event and it has an `inputType` of either `insertParagraph` (Enter) or `insertLineBreak` (Shift+Enter) you can simply cancel the event using `event.preventDefault()` and use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from getting propagated to other event listeners.

You can test this yourself using this HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Write in the contentEditable div below!</p>
<div contentEditable="true" style="width:100%;height:200px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('beforeinput', event => {
    const {
      dataTransfer,
      inputType,
      isComposing,
      data,
    } = event;

    if (dataTransfer) {
      console.log('dataTransfer.getData(text/html) ===', printR(dataTransfer.getData('text/html')));
      console.log('dataTransfer.getData(text/plain) ===', printR(dataTransfer.getData('text/plain')));
    }

    const convertToRange = staticRange => {
      if (staticRange instanceof StaticRange) {
        const {
          startContainer, startOffset,
          endContainer, endOffset,
        } = staticRange;
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(startContainer, startOffset);
        range.setEnd(endContainer, endOffset);
        return range;
      }
    };

    // Get the static ranges that will be affected by a change to the DOM if the input event is not canceled
    const ranges = event.getTargetRanges?.() || [];
    ranges.forEach(staticRange => {
      const range = convertToRange(staticRange);
      console.log(`Range text content: "${range}"`);
    });
    console.log('ranges.length ==', ranges.length);

    console.log('The "inputbefore" event was detected! event ==', {
      dataTransfer,
      inputType,
      isComposing,
      data,
    });

    if (['insertParagraph', 'insertLineBreak'].includes(inputType)) {
      console.log('CANCELING event with inputType ==', inputType);
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When you press `Enter` (or `Shift`+`Enter`) you should notice nothing changing inside the `<div contentEditable="true">` element.

Comment: What are the roles played respectively by `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()` ?
EDIT : After doing some tests, it seems like  `preventDefault()` is doing the work fo actually preventing input while `stopPropagation` probably juste prevents other event listeners to be fired

Comment: @cassepipe That is correct. I've edited my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In the [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#instance_properties) interface `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are deprecated and have been replaced by [`e.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).

A list of possible values for `e.key` can be found [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values) or [here on W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#named-key-attribute-values).

To prevent possibility of typing a new line or a tab which would exit the input consider the following for react/next:

```js
onKeyDown = {(e) => {
  return ["Enter", "Tab"].includes(e.key) ? e.preventDefault() : null
}}
```

Answer (score -5):

Use CSS:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

For me, its worked!